# Rails 3. Where NOT query. How to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an API in Rails 3 and I let the users search the User table to find friends but I do not want them to find them self in the search results. How can I alter the below query to make sure that the users ID is not among the query results.

```
User.where("LOWER (firstname) LIKE ? OR LOWER (lastname) LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%" , "%#{@query}%")
```

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition to your query:

```
User.where("(LOWER (firstname) LIKE ? OR LOWER (lastname) LIKE ?) AND (id != ?)", "%#{@query}%" , "%#{@query}%", current_user.id)
```